# Expected value and Maximum Likelihood Estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, mean, likelihood, poisson-distribution

I'm doing this exercise about Poisson distribution and maximum likelihood estimation:
[image: 1576858074177.png]

I have had no problem with points a and b, but I'm struggling with the correct answers of the C part.
From my notes, I know that
[image] and [image: 1576858439953.png]
 but I don't know what are the procedures and the computations that bring us to these results. In other terms, I haven't understood how to proceed to compute the expected value and the value of an estimator.
Can you help me with it?

Comment: Have you tried to plug in the formula for the estimator into the expected value and apply rules for expected values like linearity?

Comment: Can you explicitly determine the estimator & then do what Christoph Hanck suggests? Also these type of questions require the self-study tag.

Comment: If I'm right, to determine the estimator I have to derive the function with respect to the estimator (lambda), and then put that derivative equal to zero in order to compute lambda (in other words, I'm maximizing the likelihood function). Then I don't know how to continue to have the expected value and the variance of the estimator.